# Is there a quick way to redirect output in Perl?

Tags: perl

In **Perl** this takes 6 lines:

```
my $rpt = 'report.txt';
open my $f, '>', $rpt or die "$0: cannot open $rpt: $!\n";
select $f;
print_report($a, $b, $c);
close $f;
select STDOUT;
```

In **Bash** this takes 1 line:

```
print_report $a $b $c >report.txt
```

Is there a way to trim down the Perl code?

Comment: `perl script_that_runs_print_report.pl > report.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple redirect if you don't need to restore `STDOUT`

```
my $rpt = 'report.txt';
open STDOUT, '>', $rpt or die "$0: cannot open $rpt: $!\n";
print_report($a, $b, $c);
```

Answer (score 7):

That's because you're cheating. You don't have to store the report name in a variable, select the filehandle, or close it, to print to a file...

```
open my $fh, '>', 'report.txt' or die "$0: cannot open $fh: $!\n";
print $fh func($a, $b, $c);
```

Alas, per [mob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168657/mob) if you want to redirect `STDOUT` use shell redirection. If you don't want STDOUT to default to the terminal, it makes sense to change it where the default cascades to the program,

```
perl script_that_runs_print_report.pl > report.txt
```

Comment: Good point on using $fh to pick up the file name. That's worth 1 line of code. The rest, no, I prefer to use lots of print functions (that actually print) rather than cat'ing everything up in memory and returning it as a string.

Comment: @jeberle, then pass the filehandle as an argument to your `print_report` function.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's about the best that can be done. Thought I'd throw it out there.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;

sub into (&$) {
  open my $f, '>', $_[1] or die "$0: cannot open $_[1]: $!";
  my $old = select $f;
  $_[0]->();
  select $old
}

sub fake {
  say 'lalala';
  say for @_;
}

say 'before';
into { fake(1, 2, 3); say 4 } 'report.txt';
say 'after';
```

Usage:

```
$ perl example
before
after
$ cat report.txt
lalala
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Better to `local()`ize *STDOUT in `into()`, in case the user-supplied sub `die()`s.